# Awk If, If Else, Else Statement get data from multiple files

Tags: grep, awk

I have 10000 text files.
I have some files containing **firstprice** and **secondprice** and other files containing only **firstprice**. I want to get **secondprice** only if available, if not available then get **firstprice** with FILENAME as prefix like this:

**FILENAME:DATA**

10000.txt

```
window.firstprice="20.0";
window.secondprice="10.0";
```

20000.txt

```
window.firstprice="5.0";
```

30000.txt

```
window.firstprice="40.0";
window.secondprice="30.0";
```

I want to get data from all 10k files using **awk** or **perl** or **grep** or other tools.

I tried this but it's working only if i extract DATA from one file, but it's not working when I use *.txt to get data from all text files in directory:

```
awk -F'"' -v val="begin" ' BEGIN{ OFS="," } FNR==1{ if(val!="begin") { print val?val:"NO" } val="" } /.secondprice=/{ minval=(minval?minval OFS:"")$(NF-1) } /.firstprice=/{ val=(val?val OFS:"")$(NF-1) } END{ split(FILENAME,a,/.txt/); if (minval=="") {print a[1]":"val } else { print a[1]":"minval}} ' *.txt
```

Desired output:

```
10000:10.0
20000:5.0
30000:30.0
```

Comment: Do `firtsprice` and `secondprice` always appear in order (in which case you can take the last occurrence)? Do the files contain anything else?

Comment: i get a duplicate results like this : `10.0 5.0 5.0 30.0 30.0` i dont know why

Comment: is this a school assignment ?  why the requirement to use awk ?  there are many other ways to solve this without awk so update your question with these answers so we can help you

Comment: @ScottStensland i dont any idea about other ways, please can share with me your solution i changed my question .